# div tags are floating with the codes above

Tags: html

I am working with html. I am getting problem with html div tag.

see the code above:-

```
<html>
<body>

<h3>This is a header</h3>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<style>
div {float:left;width:200px;}
</style>
<div style="color:#00FF00">
  <h3>This is a header</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div style="color:blue;">
  <h3>This is a header</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
This is a text
</body>
</html>
```

Here, the divs are floated left. But the text "This is a text" is also floated with the divs. I want the text "This is a text" to be situated after the divs. Not beside them. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add a div before "This is a text" :

```
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to clear the float ...

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
   <div style="color:blue;">
      <h3>This is a header</h3>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
   </div>
   <div style='clear:both'></div>
        This is a text
```